# Does heroku automatically update the repository?

Tags: python, github, heroku

I have a heroku app deployed. In that app, whenever something happens, my program stores the logs in a file. But the logs are not showing in my github repository. How can I get the logs stored in the file and the file kepp getting updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) makes file-based logging impractical. Any changes you make to the filesystem will be lost the next time your dyno restarts. This happens frequently ([at least once per day](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts)).

Logs should [simply be printed to `stdout` or `stderr`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log). Heroku will capture them and include them in its log stream, which you can view by [running `heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs-with-the-heroku-cli) or via the dashboard.

The log stream [doesn't keep very many logs, or store them for very long](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-history-limits), but you can use a logging add-on or implement a log drain if you wish:

> Logplex is designed for collating and routing log messages, not for storage. It retains the most recent 1,500 lines of your consolidated logs, which expire after 1 week.
>
> For more production-ready persistence of logs, add one of the Heroku platform’s available [logging add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#logging) to your app. Most of these add-ons offer a free plan to get started.
>
> Alternatively, implement your own [log drains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains) for full control over what happens to your logs.

Comment: Thanks you sir. But I am not able to understand log drain. How can I have a log drain so that I can store the logs on my computer or any online free host?

Comment: All of the logging add-ons have free tiers. Just provision one and away you go. But those free tiers have limits; you won't be able to store all logs indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks I just forwarded those logs to a telegram group that I made. Now that group has become my logs group.